# Update Microsoft Azure account password from php as Organization

Tags: php, api, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-account

I am currently trying to sync the password a user is using on my website (simple Php and Mysql) with the password of an account on Microsoft that I have created for them.
So basically they all have a **{user_id}@mydomain.com** account with a random password, and if they want to use it they basically re-enter their password on a dedicated page on the client area of my website, so that I make an API call and update the random password with their own.

- I am working without a signed-in user (for obvious reasons)
- I have correctly set up the required "application permissions":  *User.ReadWrite.All, User.ManageIdentities.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All*

BUT, it says I don't have enough permissions:

```
array(1) { ["error"]=> array(3) { ["code"]=> string(27) "Authorization_RequestDenied" ["message"]=> string(50) "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." ["innerError"]=> array(2) { ["request-id"]=> string(36) "acb8b9c7-6a63-4157-8c92-de5f49a69ac8" ["date"]=> string(19) "2020-04-30T17:13:04" } } }
```

This is the code I am currently using to update the password, in case it helps:

```
$password = array(
                    'forceChangePasswordNextSignIn' => false,
                    'forceChangePasswordNextSignInWithMfa' => false,
                    'password' => $_POST['password']
                );

                $data = array(
                    'passwordProfile' => $password
                );

                $updatePassword = patch_microsoft_graph('users/'.$userID,$data,true);
```

I also leave you the reference for the patch_microsoft_graph() function:

```
function patch_microsoft_graph($scope,$data,$object) {

            $access_token = get_microsoft_access_token();

            if(!$scope) {
                return 'no $scope';
            }


            $payload = json_encode($data);


            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$scope");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

            $headers = [
                "Authorization: $access_token",
                "Host: graph.microsoft.com",
                "Content-Type: application/json",
                "Accept: application/json"
            ];

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

            $server_output = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close ($ch);

            return json_decode($server_output,$object);
        }
```

Can someone help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Here's the [related documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for the API call. So just make sure you set the correct permissions (whether you're using Application or delegated permissions, as per the document.)
- Also please check whether the account that you're using to update the password has any roles assigned. Say, when updating the passwordProfile property, the following permission is required: Directory.AccessAsUser.All. In case, if you're updating another user's businessPhones, mobilePhone, or otherMails property is only allowed on users who are non-administrators or assigned one of the following roles: Directory Readers, Guest Inviter, Message Center Reader, and Reports Reader. For more details, see Helpdesk (Password) Administrator in [Azure AD available roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#available-roles). This is the case for apps granted either the User.ReadWrite.All or Directory.ReadWrite.All delegated or application permissions.

Try the above and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hello there, I have already set the correct permissions as stated in the first message. Also, the user is a test user and does not have any role

Comment: Setting correcting permissions is one piece. But also they need to be part of the role(s) that's mentioned above.

Comment: The fact is that the page will be visible for all the users to change their password, so I can't add all the users as Helpdesk administrators